# Table name or column name length affect performance?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I'm using MySQL + Hibernate.

MySQL table name length and column name length affect application performance ?

exmaple)

```
#1
awd (table)
id int,
awd_nm varchar(...),
tit varchar(...)

#2
award (table)
id int,
award_name varchar(...),
title varchar(...)
```

which is better ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No it will not, not to any degree that you can measure.

Spend more effort making your schema easy to understand. You'll gain more in the long (and short) term than the unmeasurable femtoseconds you'll gain with shorter and unreadable schema names.

Answer (score 7):

The amount of performance degradation is so miniscule (if even existent) that I would worry more about the actual data type used more then the title.  You should read http://www.codeforest.net/8-great-mysql-performance-tips for a jumping off point.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers alluded to, there is a small performance penalty with longer field names.

However, the type of optimization that you propose make the schema less maintainable. What should be avoided is long names such as

```
product_variant_review_feature_keyword
```

which, though perhaps semantically makes the most sense, is too costly for repeated joins.

Comment: Too costly in what way?