# Key length impact on queries performance?

Tags: database, wordpress

I've noticed that my `meta_keys` are getting pretty long, e.g `user_event_first_impression_ratings` and I retrieve most of the data with WordPress functions e.g `get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key);`

I've thought about this often - there's no way to make shorter names because I've got a lot of different things going on and not naming them like that would lose its purpose which is *understanding quicky in phpMyAdmin and code what and where is going on*.

I've thought of making a table (in excel for example) where I give very short, like 2-3 digit numberic codes for every `meta_key`, replace them and then use that to navigate in database and code. Im sure that I would know all these codes by heart pretty soon.

- **Does `meta_key` length have any impact to queries and get_meta-s performance?**
- **String vs integer?**

Let's leave query quality out of this and pretend that query is well written.

---

If some of you is not familiar with WordPress database, here's an example:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| meta_id (unique row nr) | post id |    meta_key      |    meta_value   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
|            1            |   343   |  my_event_color  |     red         |
|            2            |   623   |  my_event_id     |     235         |
|            3            |   423   |  my_event_lenght |     537644      |
|            4            |   243   |  my_event_name   |     tortilla    |
|            5            |   732   |  my_event_is_xxx |     1           |
|           ...           |   ...   |       ...        |      ...        |

   Etc for many, many, many rows - meta_id is only unique number here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your first question, no. Or the difference in performance between a long key and a short key is so tiny as to not make it worth thinking about. So don't worry about your excel reference table.

See the following:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91057/does-the-length-of-the-index-name-have-any-performance-impact
- [Table name or column name length affect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762794/table-name-or-column-name-length-affect-performance)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91057/does-the-length-of-the-index-name-have-any-performance-impact

To your second question I don't really understand what you're asking.